# Ansible 2.7 include_tasks no longer accepts a variable

Tags: ansible

Each of the roles in my playbook ends with this code:

```
- include_tasks: includes/log_role_completion.yml this_role={{ role_name }}
```

Which is used (at the end of the playbook) to write a log on the target server,
indicating when a PB was started (there's a task at the start of the PB for that), what roles ran, and when (the start and end-times are the same, but that's for another day).

The problem is that with Ansible 2.7, I'm now getting an error caused by the line above:

```
- include_tasks: includes/log_role_completion.yml this_role="{{ role_name }}"
  ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:
```

This worked up until 2.7, and is useful - I'd hate to have to lose it.  I've tried putting quotes around the "includes...}}" part of the line, to no avail.

PS I know that Ansible can write logs - I find this more useful. Also, I'm aware that include_tasks is marked 'preview', so may change, but I can't find release notes to tell me if it has.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The usage has been changed in Ansible 2.7.

> OLD In Ansible 2.6 (and earlier) the following was valid syntax for specifying variables:

```
- include_tasks: include_me.yml variable=value    #the old way
```

> NEW In Ansible 2.7 the task should be changed to use the vars keyword:

```
- include_tasks: include_me.yml
  vars:
    variable: value
```

Check out the [Porting Guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/porting_guides/porting_guide_2.7.html#include-tasks-import-tasks-inline-variables) for more details

Comment: Thanks so much - saved me lots of hassle!

Comment: To anyone else coming here - this is the correct answer, and the ref to the porting guide is useful - in skim-reading the docs I'd not realised that the porting guide refers to moving code from previous releases of Ansible to this one.

Comment: the previous way of doing it was a "bug" that is now "fixed" in 2.7

Comment: @SimplySeth the fixing *needlessly* broke my script and makes me aware again why to always avoid ansible as much as possible